# how to make this javascript shrinking header work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have been working on making a shrinking header with javascript, and while I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prohizzlewizzle/1350jck3/) working exactly how I want it, I can't seem to get it to work outside of the fiddle.
What is wrong with this html?

```
<body>
    <div id='sizeShifter'>
        Here is my website's header
    </div>
    <div id='spacer'></div>
    <div id='content'>
        Here is my website's content
    </div>


     <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var divToChange = $('#sizeShifter');
    var lastScroll = 0;
    $(document).scroll(function(event){
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        var divHeight = 400-st;
        divToChange.css({height:divHeight});
    });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not a lot is happening in the fiddle, so really unclear what the issue is.

Comment: Can you post any console errors? I think it's because of where you have your script tags

Comment: Please describe what is the issue you are seeing, what results you are getting and how they differ from what you want.

Comment: Do you have an opening `<html>` and `<head></head>` tags that you didn't post? Are you referencing jQuery and your css properly?

Comment: In your fiddle you have set to wrap all your code within the window onLoad function, which you did not do in your HTML. This might cause issues where the DOM isn't ready yet. Either wrap your code with `$(function(){...});` (which I recommend, and works) or `$(window).load(function(){...});` (I would not recommended but also works).

Comment: if it is working in fiddle it will be difficult for us to find the problem...may be you can post your console errors here

Answer (score 1):

I can see few issues in your code.

1. You didn't add CSS file, which is present in fiddle.
2. `jquery-2.1.3.min.js` file might not be at correct location. BTW, it is preferred we use jquery from `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js` or `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js`, unless you have modified version of jquery.

If you can fix them, your code should work :)